# should I put two similar Actions in two separate methods with two routes or merge in to one in play framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have two actions, one takes "id" and "event" as input and save to database, the other takes "id", "event", and "thirdparty" as input and save to database. The process is similar but a bit different. With "thirdparty" I don't need to check database for "event" related "thirdparty".

The question is, which one gives the best performance? One route with some switching logic? or two routes with two separate actions?

I'm using scala play 2.5.x and cassandra database.

To be more general, is it a better practice to have more routes? or fewer routes but more complicated logic?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is the same (except for the switch, which is negligible) the performance is the same. It's more a matter of how you want to structure your code and your endpoints to avoid code duplication and have a coherent endpoint list.

It's really application specific so it's hard to suggest one or another. Both are correct depending on how your application is structured.

---

In terms of performance is basically the same because each request is independent, the only difference would be an `if` to check whether or not the third party should be invoked.

Regarding to best practices, if you have other routes with optional arguments and switch logic I would probably choose that one to maintain coherence in the code. If not, you should group routes that make sense together as long as the code does not get too complicated - if the code gets complicated is a sign that they shouldn't be grouped together anyway.

For this case, my gut feeling is to use only route because contacting the third party seems like a simple extra step, but it is really up to you to decide. Both options are correct.

Comment: I was more curious about whether it will make a difference at all in terms of performance. Is it a better practice to have more routes? or fewer routes but more complicated logic?

Comment: @yang If the code gets too complicated is a sign that an endpoint may be doing too many things and you should refactor. In this case, it looks like a simple extra step. I updated the answer with more insights